# Python Kafka Consumer Library that supports scalability and recoverability

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Basically, I have a use case where I'm trying to set up a python process to run in containers on EKS to consume data from Kafka and process the same. So far, I've gathered that I could consider using the following three frameworks for this:

1. Apache Spark(Pyspark)
2. kafka-python Module
3. Confluent-kafka-python Module.

I'm looking for a solution that has the following features:

1. Seamless scalability
2. If a container dies, and it gets spun up again, it should know where to pick up the offset where it left off from.

Any advice on which of the above mentioned libraries would be most suitable for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We do have similar set up kafka,python and EKS we are using confluent Kafka Module so far we don't come across any scalability and data integrity issues

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is considered off topic per [help]. Instead, please try one (or all) and report back if you any issues. Each one of these supports the features you've asked for

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking for a mere library, I would avoid PySpark since it's a whole framework with it's own deployment model that is going to have a major impact on how you structure your application. Unless you explicitly know that you need the specific features of Spark, I would skip this one. Similarly, Apache Flink and Beam frameworks exist with Python support.

[Confluent Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) is a Python wrapper around the librdkafka C library, so you have the guarantee it's going to be the most performant and compatible option. Also, since it's maintained by Confluent it should continue being updated by very knowledgeable professional in the long term: it's a dependable solution.

You also have [Kafka python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)  which is implemented fully in python. It might "feel" more pythonic, but may also be less performant. At the time of writing this the repo does not show a lot of recent activity.

There's also [faust-streaming](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust) that aimed to be Kafka Streams-like, and `aiokafka` which uses AsyncIO support

Comment: Pykafka is archived and no longer maintained

Comment: Oh indeed, thanks for the heads up, I'll remove it from my answer then